# Error - while executing- JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I ran this line of code and got the error mentioned in title. Can someone tell me what is happening?

```py
x = requests.get('https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/india/status/confirmed').json()
```

I have imported the following libraries

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request might return 404. If that's the case, you can't decode the error pages. Therefore the following code might be a better choice:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/india/status/confirmed')
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    response_json = response.json()
else:
    print(f"Error! Status code: {response.status_code}")
```